# Retain existing file during auto update C#

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have already developed an `windows mobile app` using c# in `compact framework 3.5`. I implemented the auto upgrade functionality like this, if new version is released, my app download the new version, uninstall the existing version and install the new version. This is working fine.

I need to accomplish the following during the auto upgrade,
After install the new version I need to retain some user modified xml file from the old version app and replace the same file in newly installed app. I need to retain the existing settings xml file in newly installed version. How to implement this in `compact framework 3.5`

Comment: Where are you storing the settings xml file? Maybe move it to a subfolder in the documents folder or elsewhere as appropriate?

Comment: How are you installing the original app and updates?  Via CAB file, or just individual files?

Comment: @ctacke I am installing and updating the App via CAB file.

Answer (score 1):

When a CAB is uninstalled, all files that it installed are removed. There are three general ways to circumvent that behavior for app data files:

1. Have your app create the data file in the first place, not the CAB file.  If the CAB doesn't place the file, it won't delete it.  This is a common mechanism for configurations and databases that don't need seed data.
2. Rename or move the file you want to keep.  If the CAB installer can't find a file, it can't delete it.  You might ship your data file, or whatever file you want to keep, with a "fake" name, and when the app runs, look for the fake-named file and rename it to the name you want.  This also provides the ability to actually update the file if you want to through some app logic.
3. Create a [custom setup DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx) (in C) and do something in the `Uninstall_Init` function to move or prevent the deletion, then include that DLL in your CAB file.